# Three.js example not completely compatible with mobile

Tags: three.js, glsl

I'm having issues with the "postprocessing / glitch" example on mobile. It's just the snow effect that's causing trouble. On desktop it covers the entire view port during a glitch. On mobile it's only appearing at the bottom. I think this is the line responsible. It's within DigitalGlitch.js.

```
"vec4 snow = 200.*amount*vec4(rand(vec2(xs * seed,ys * seed*50.))*0.2);",
```

I don't see why mobile should be effected.

Comment: what do you expect the `vec4()` out of a `vec2()` to be?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm not sure what the value should be. That's the value within the current shader. Every thing looks good when viewed from a desktop bowser but the snow effect does not appear right on mobile. Test it out and you'll see what I mean. Here's a link to the example http://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_postprocessing_glitch

Comment: Also the very next line after the one mentioned in my post is. gl_FragColor = gl_FragColor+ snow;. I was thinking maybe this syntax needs to be changed for mobile. I'm still very new to GLSL.

Comment: my bad. `rand()` returns a float so the code looks fine.

Comment: Yea I wasn't sure how that worked. Thanks for clearing that up. I wish there was some way to use console log with GLSL. So I could compare the  gl_fragColor values between desktop and mobile. I was thinking maybe there is a WebGL extension needed that is not available on mobile. I'm not sure how to test for that.

Comment: there is a shader editor extension at https://github.com/spite/ShaderEditorExtension but I don't know how it would work on mobile.

Comment: O yea I've used that on desktop but I never thought to try it on mobile. If it works it should speed up trouble shooting.

Comment: Can you provide more details on your "mobile" environment?  I could not reproduce the issue on my iPhone in Safari or Chrome.

Comment: Thanks for the update @AdamFinley. I'm using a fire and tested with the slik browser and firefox. Do you have any other mobile devices you can test on?

Comment: I also tried IE in Windows Phone 8.1.  Three.js doesn't work at all.  You could try debugging Silk remotely: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/silk/latest/developerguide/remote-debugging.html

Comment: Thanks for the tip. If it's working on your iPhone than it's either an issue with some browsers not supporting all of the WebGL extensions needed or the way my device is rendering the shader. Could you test with firefox on your iPhone?

Answer (score 0):

This issue is most common in mobile devices one of the reason behind this device pixel ratio
Normally mobile devices have pixel ratio > 2
a pixel ratio of 2 means 4 times more pixels to render

to optimize the performance we have to normalize this, and You can try -

```
  renderer.setPixelRatio(Math.min(window.devicePixelRatio, 2));
```